# Styles from stylesheet is not applied

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to style a component but it doesn't look like the styles that I'm using is getting applied.

toolTipStyle gets prop-drilled down to the component but and I can see that they exist if I console.log them.

```
export const LinkCopiedToolTip = ({
  disclaimerText,
  isDesktop,
  tooltipStyle,
  setHasCopiedInvitationLink,
}) => {
  const [fadeOutTooltip, setFadeOutTooltip] = useState<boolean>(false)

...
...
...

  return (
    <View style={{ ...tooltipStyle.tooltipContainer, ...(fadeOutTooltip && tooltipStyle.fadeOut) }}>
      <Tooltip hasFluidWidth arrow={isDesktop ? 'left' : 'top'}>
        {disclaimerText}
      </Tooltip>
    </View>
  )
}
```

The component LinkCopiedToolTip gets rendered depending on the state `hasCopiedInvitationLink` like this in a parent component:

```
{hasCopiedInvitationLink && (
          <LinkCopiedToolTip
            disclaimerText={disclaimerText}
            isDesktop={isDesktop}
            tooltipStyle={{ ...tooltipContainer, ...fadeOut }}
            setHasCopiedInvitationLink={setHasCopiedInvitationLink}
          />
        )}
```

Any takes :)? I'm at my wits end here. Thanks!

Tried a bunch of stuff. If I just hardcode the styles directly it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access properties that do not exist on `tooltipStyle`:

`<View style={{ ...tooltipStyle.tooltipContainer, ...(fadeOutTooltip && tooltipStyle.fadeOut) }}>`

To get this to work you need to update the syntax where the styles are fed to `LinkCopiedToolTip` and remove the spread (`...`) operator:

`tooltipStyle={{ tooltipContainer, fadeOut }}`

Comment: Yep, that was it /facepalm
Thanks heaps!